# how to find Clang folder on OSX?

Tags: c, macos, shell, clang, llvm

I could ran clang with command line and i thought my clang is the default one.

I could ran command like this.

clang -cc1 -analyze -analyzer-checker=debug.DumpCFG  a.c

I want to find the source code from clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers,but i cannot find the clang folder.

I have tried to search it with finder,ended failure.

Is there any shell command to find where is the command stored?

Answer (score 1):

The file location is here:

```
/usr/local/llvm/tools/clang/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers/
```

or

```
/opt/local/libexec/llvm-x.x/include/clang/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers
```

by an `ls` command you can find all the source codes int his list:

> https://github.com/CTSRD-CHERI/clang/tree/master/lib/StaticAnalyzer/Checkers

Hope that's what you're looking for!